# Delphi click image through coding

Tags: delphi

I am doing a project where if you push an image the image would cause another button press through coding.

I have tried `Image.click;` , `Image.OnClick := Imageclick;`

```
procedure TForm1.RandomRekenaar;
var
  z: integer;
begin
  z := 0;
  if (rgpSpelTipe.ItemIndex = 0) and (rgpSpelers.ItemIndex = 2) then
  begin
    z := Random(16 - 1 + 1);
    case z of
      1:
          if Prent41.Visible <> False 
          then Prent41.OnClick := Prent41Click
          else RandomRekenaar;
      2:
        begin
          if Prent42.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent42.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      3:
        begin
          if Prent43.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent43.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      4:
        begin
          if Prent44.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent44.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      5:
        begin
          if Prent45.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent45.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      6:
        begin
          if Prent46.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent46.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      7:
        begin
          if Prent47.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent47.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      8:
        begin
          if Prent48.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent48.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      9:
        begin
          if Prent49.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent49.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      10:
        begin
          if Prent410.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent410.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      11:
        begin
          if Prent411.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent411.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      12:
        begin
          if Prent412.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent412.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      13:
        begin
          if Prent413.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent413.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      14:
        begin
          if Prent414.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent414.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      15:
        begin
          if Prent415.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent415.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;
      16:
        begin
          if Prent416.Visible <> False then
          begin
            Prent416.Click;
          end
          else
          begin
            RandomRekenaar;
          end;
        end;

    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask kindly read this and Also put detail of events which you wrote onClick

Comment: I put want to code this in a procedure. This procedure should generate a random number to select a randon image. If the image is selected the image should chang

Comment: Did you read the link Ajay provided. You will find there that you need to provide the code you have tried until now, whether it is working or not. Code needs to demonstrate the problem, with proper variable declarations as well as function, procedure and method declarations and implementations. Please [edit] your question and add the code.

Comment: You say: *... if you push an image...*, but there are no images in the code, *... another button press...*, but there are no buttons. What are `Prent41`, `Prent42` etc.? What does `Prent42.Click` (and all other `PrentXX.Click`) do? Please explain, and be verbose. I repeat: **Code needs to demonstrate the problem, with proper variable declarations as well as function, procedure and method declarations and implementations.**

Comment: No need to write so many begin/end for such a small program.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows:

```
ImageClick(Image);
```

Anyhow, I suggest to define a separated function:

```
procedure TForm1.SelectRandomImage();
begin
  //...
end;


procedure TForm1.ImageClick(Sender : TObject);
begin
  SelectRandomImage();
end;
```

In this way, you could call `SelectRandomImage` procedure directly and I think the code would be more readable.

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: @user11747134 "it did not work" is not a useful problem description.  If sometime takes the time and trouble to write you an answer, you should at least take the trouble to explain what you mean by "did not work".

Comment: @user11747134 could you explain what did not work?

Answer (score 1):

Try something more like this:

```pascal
var
  Images: array[0..15] of TImage;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Images[0] := Prent41;
  Images[1] := Prent42;
  ...
  Images[15] := Prent416;

  { or:
  for I := 0 to 15 do
    Images[I] := TImage(FindComponent('Prent4'+IntToStr(I+1)));
  }
end;

function TForm1.RandomImage: TImage;
var
  VisibleImages: array[0..15] of TImage;
  I, Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  Count := 0;
  for I := 0 to 15 do
  begin
    if Images[I].Visible then
    begin
      VisibleImages[Count] := Images[I];
      Inc(Count);
    end;
  end;
  if Count > 0 then
    Result := VisibleImages[Random(Count)];
end;

procedure TForm1.RandomRekenaar;
var
  Image: TImage;
begin
 if (rgpSpelTipe.ItemIndex = 0) and (rgpSpelers.ItemIndex = 2) then
 begin
   Image := RandomImage;
   if Image <> nil then
     Image.Click; // or Image.OnClick(Image);
  end;
end;
```